# Globally offline node goes online but txs that were broadcast to it while off the net are not broadcast when it goes fully online

Tags: network, broadcast, offline-transactions

I have a Bitcoin Core node that I disconnected from the *internet* while keeping it on a hub with a laptop.  I sent a transaction to that node from my laptop (via a local Electrum server).  Now I put the node fully online with the internet (after disconnected my laptop...) expecting this one new transaction to get sent to the Bitcoin network after my node synced up (which took just seconds, it was offline only a few minutes).

However: This new Tx did *not* get broadcast to the network.  A mempool explorer connected to only that node showed the Tx, but a mempool explorer connected to a node in the world at large *did not*.  Waited 15 minutes.

I had to go to my node, dump the Tx in hex, then send it (from that node, fully online) via `sendrawtransaction` before it showed up on the network.

(So I assume that's the expected behavior. Is it?)

Question: Is there any way to "kick" my node, when it goes back online to the world and is synced again, to send its "new" transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core nodes only relay transactions once when they first learn about them. Only the Bitcoin Core *wallet* will rebroadcast its own transactions (I think once every 24h).

Since your computer was offline when it first learned about the new transaction it is indeed expected that it did not relay the transaction, since it had no peers at that time.

Exporting and reimporting seems like a fine workaround. Alternatively, you could create the transaction offline and then transfer it by means of a QR code or USB stick to an online device to broadcast.